# Launch an external .pps file with a Flash button

Tags: flash, actionscript, powerpoint

I have a flash application in which there is a button. On clicking that button, a pps file should play. What I did is published the flash file in a projector format (.exe), created a folder named 'fscommand' and put the pps file inside that folder, and tried to launch the file lying inside that folder from this flash file by using following codes:

```
on (release) {  fscommand ("exec", "file.pps"); }
```

Another way I tried which I found is:
created a .bat file named launch.bat, put it in that folder & tried to launch the pps file via this .bat file using following codes:

Actionscript code:

```
on (release) {  fscommand ("exec", "launch.bat"); }
```

'launch.bat' file code:

```
START "file.pps"
```

But still it's not working. Please help where am I wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you doubleclick the PPS (ie, in Windows Explorer or the Finder)?
If it doesn't launch the presentation in slideshow mode, there's something amiss with the file associations on the computer or PPT/the viewer isn't installed so there's nothing to play the file.

If doubleclicked PPS files play as expected, then it might be a path issue.  I don't know how Flash behaves, but in some apps you can't always assume that the path will be set to the path of the current document or app/exe file.

As a test, try hardcoding the path to the PPS in your EXE.